# Understanding the solution to ODE using differential operator theory with basic algebra

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, formal-power-series

Consider the following constant-coefficient ODE with $f\in C^\omega(A)$, where $A$ is an interval:
$$a_n\frac{d^n}{dx^n}y+\cdots+a_0y=f(x)$$
It can be written as $$P(D)(y)=f(x),$$ where $P$ is a polynomial and $D=\frac d{dx}$.
Consider formal power series ring $R=\mathbb C[[D]]$, we are now able to view $P$ as an element of $R$ and to view $C^\omega(A)$ as a $\mathbb C[D]$-module.
Back to a specific example, $$(D^2+1)y=f(x).$$
I was told that I can multiply $\frac1{D^2+1}$ to both sides and get one particular solution
$$y^\ast=\frac1{D^2+1}f(x)$$
Now the problem arose.

> i) As $$\frac1{D^2+1}=1-D^2+D^4-D^6+\cdots=:Q(D)\in\mathbb C[[D]],$$
>   to my best knowledge, I don't know how to calculate $Q(D)f$, in other words, *how can we handle the situation that* $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-D^2)^nf(x)$ *does not converge pointwise*?
>   ii) For all formal power series $P\in R$ and all analytic function $f$, is there a general definition for $P(D)f(x)$, regardless of the convergence of the series?

Comment: You can do even more, $\frac1{1+D^2}=\frac{1+a}{1+a+(1+a)D^2}=(1+a)(1-[a+(1+a)D^2]+[a+(1+a)D^2]^2-[a+(1+a)D^2]^3+...$

Comment: You have just to note that $(D^2+1)^{-1}f(x)=\int dx'G(x-x')f(x')$, being $G(x-x')$ a fundamental solution of the equation $P(D)G=\delta$.

Comment: Some information [here](http://egyankosh.ac.in/bitstream/123456789/18007/1/Unit-8.pdf)